# Group Policy Preferences in Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am reinstalling a Domain Controller after a hard drive failure (new backup system is already in place!) and I have come to the part where I need to re-create the group policies.

Originally we were using GP Preferences to add printers and drive mappings. For some reason I no longer see the options after re-installing the OS (Windows Server 2008 R2). I am using the same installation media that I did the first time.

I used to see another section below both Computer Configuration and User Configuration.

Am I forgetting to install/enable something?

[image: Server 2008 R2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're creating a Starter GPO. I tested this out in one of my environments, and I get the same `Administrative Templates` when I create a new Starter GPO.

In `Group Policy Management` try creating a "new" policy under `Group Policy Objects` rather than under the `Starter GPOs`.

And link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753200.aspx